# Using method references as listeners with observer pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern, method-reference

the usage of method references as listeners in an observer pattern does not work.
Example:

```
    public class ObserverWithMethodReferenceAsListenerTest {

    class ListenerCurator {

        private final Set<Consumer<String>> listeners = new HashSet<>();

        public boolean register(final Consumer<String> consumer) {
            return this.listeners.add(consumer);
        }

        public boolean unregister(final Consumer<String> consumer) {
            return this.listeners.remove(consumer);
        }

        public int getListenersCount() {
            return this.listeners.size();
        }

    }

    class MyListenerLeaks {

        public void theListener(final String someString) {
            // the listener
        }
    }

    class MyListenerWorks {

        public Consumer<String> consumer = str -> {
            theListener(str);

        };

        public void theListener(final String someString) {
            // the listener
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testListenerLeak() {

        ListenerCurator lc = new ListenerCurator();
        MyListenerLeaks ml = new MyListenerLeaks();

        lc.register(ml::theListener);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, lc.getListenersCount());

        lc.register(ml::theListener);
        // expected 1 but there are 2 listeners

        lc.unregister(ml::theListener);
        // there are 2 listeners registered here

    }

    @Test
    public void testListenerWorks() {
        ListenerCurator lc = new ListenerCurator();
        MyListenerWorks ml = new MyListenerWorks();

        lc.register(ml.consumer);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, lc.getListenersCount());

        lc.register(ml.consumer);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, lc.getListenersCount());

        lc.unregister(ml.consumer);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, lc.getListenersCount());
    }
}
```

Conclusion: each referencing of the listener method with ml::theListener generates a new object id for the reference? Right? Therefore there a multiple listeners registered and cannot be removed individually?

The MyListenerWorks class uses a member with a "constant" object id and works. Is there another workaround for this? Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: You can change the field declaration in `MyListenerWorks` to `public Consumer<String> consumer = this::theListener;` The behavior does not depend on whether you use a method reference, lambda expresion, or even a good old anonymous inner class, i.e. `new Consumer<String>() { public void accept(String str) { theListener(str); } } `. It only depends on the overall code structure, i.e. whether you remember the instantiated object or not. I’ve never seen an event source keeping listeners in a `Set`, by the way.

Comment: If set or not....this does not change the main problem ;) ...what do you think is wrong using a set instead of a list?

Comment: Registering the same listener twice, followed by unregistering it only once should leave one registered listener. Not using a Set doesn’t change the fact that method references have unspecified object identity, but using a Set makes it even worse. If I do `button.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("hello"));` twice, I can be sure that pressing the button will print the message twice. If the button used a Set, it would be unspecified whether it prints once or twice on an event.

Comment: The set makes sense if the conumer implements hashCode and equals....yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added some breakpoints to the HashSet#add and remove function.
I got some results for your questions in the images below:

[image]

*1. each referencing of the listener method with ml::theListener generates a new object id for the reference? Right?*

**Ans: No. It would generate a new memory address into the HashSet. There would not be an object id. So in the test function:testListenerLeak, you cannot remove the listener correspondingly. Since you didn't get the listeners from the set before you remove it.**

*2. The MyListenerWorks class uses a member with a "constant" object id and works. Is there another workaround for this? Are my assumptions correct?*

You could take a look of the Observer pattern in Spring, Vue, or some other famous project. they have something similar to what you want. But mostly I have ever read about this pattern is in the Event-driven model. They use the "instanceOf" to check the subclasses and their superclass.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) on Method References:

> Method references enable you to do this; they are compact, easy-to-read lambda expressions for methods that already have a name.

A method reference is not a **constant**.

Comment: Ok....but I would have expected that a method reference to the same method of the same object will be the same.

Comment: It is a reference to a method of an object. That is the only guarantee you have here. In other words: you shouldn't **assume** properties of language constructs unless they are explicitly described that way in the language specification.

Comment: In fact, the identity of the objects created by method references is explicitly described as (intentionally) unspecified.